# absolute position background image

Tags: css, image, background, absolute

I need to achieve the following, a div which holds an image which is CMS managed and also has an option to display a background color, all the content will overlap this background image.

Since the image is CMS managed I have to insert an image tag....

```
<HEADER>

<div> image tag placed here</div> -------this div is absolutely positioned which is
 used to show the image in the background or color. 
<CONTENT>

<FOOTER>
```

I struggling with the layout when no image is displayed and it has to just show a background color as it is not covering the background of the content fully.

Any help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how can i acheive background image and color to show in the background and the content to overlap....

Answer (score 0):

There is really no way to change the color trough CMS except if you ask the user to upload a 1x1 gif with the color they need.

Unless your CMS has color-picker and allows the user to choose color or image

I'm thinking something like this?

```
<div style="backgound-color:red;">
  <img src="bg.jpg"/>
</div>
```

Comment: I can display a class for the color which is controlled via css and give the editor an option to select a preset colors...but the issue that i am facing is that the div wont expand the content....

<div class="red">
  <img src="bg.jpg"/>
</div>
`

Comment: The img tag needs to be "expanded" separately. The div is just container.

So <img style="width:100%; height:100%"/> 

will stretch the image but won't keep the ratio. 

I recommend using a plugin like Supersized for jQuery. Google it :)

Comment: I'd even say to spell out the dimensions of the image in your css, and then just set the div to overflow:hidden.